# How can I create a frontend for matplotlib?

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, originlab

I feel that I should start this question by mentioning that I am a Chemical Engineer and not a trained programmer (but I am willing to learn).

I process a lot of spectra, which are essentially ASCII files with x,y coordinates produced by spectrometer specific software. A standard software used for analysis is Origin from [Originlab](http://www.originlab.com/) but I find it is not user friendly, it has a lot more functions than I need and it is not free.

So I was hoping that there is a way to develop a frontend for matplotlib that allows to use matplotlib with a GUI. I want to be able to read in and plot data from ASCII files, zoom in and out in the plot, call scripts for things such as peak-detection and fitting functions where function specific parameters can be entered in the GUI.

I am simply puzzled where to start, so the question really is:
What is the easiest way to develop a frontend/GUI for matplotlib that allows me to program the things that I mentioned above? Also, ultimately, a cross platform application would be nice because many in my group work in Windows.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if you had success to build anything. I am on my way building a little GUI tool for a friend to load data from measuring apparatus, display a graph, input some parameters from user, apply curve fitting algorithm and then export the data. Maybe my work might be of any use for you. If you would like to contact me you can find my email in my profile page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out also good examples from Eli Bendersky's website:

- [matplotlib with PyQt GUIs](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/20/matplotlib-with-pyqt-guis/)
- [More PyQt plotting demos](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/05/23/more-pyqt-plotting-demos/)
- [matplotlib with wxPython GUIs](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/)

Comment: Thank you. The first link has an example on how to read in csv files. I guess that is a starting point

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. Matplotlib already has an interactive GUI, if you call it from the Python shell or ipython, for example. You read in or construct your data, and when you call `plot()`, you get a zoomable window, from which you can save an image etc.

You can write your own routines for things like peak detection, and just call them interactively from the terminal. At the end of the day, as long as your function produces a set of (x, y) data, you can plot it interactively. The experience then is rather like Matlab. This is the way most of the scientists I know use matplotlib.

I would definitely try experimenting with this approach first, and seeing if it can meet your needs, before considering any kind of GUI programming - particularly if you are not a programmer by training.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use matplotlib in the terminal, but the question was can I build a GUI that does not require me to use a terminal. This is what I found just a minute ago and it almost looks like what I am after http://github.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/tutorial_2.html

Comment: Link update for the above comment: http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/chaco_tutorial.html