# target detection using python, scipy

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I have created a program that displays 96x512 numpy arrays as images.  Within these images, there are targets (the data is an image of a sphere in a pool... this will eventually be used for fish tracking).  I have reached the point where user input via mouse click will give the target coordinates.

What I'm not even remotely sure how to do is use scipy (I'm guessing through filtering, etc... I'm still new to python) to autonomously differentiate targets (anything under X value, for example).  And then, if that target moves...say, less than 5 pixels, for target tracking.

Does anyone know if there are any good modules or guides for how to do this?

The end goal is to be able to tell how many targets there are, track their movement, and obtain the size... but that is down the road.

Edit:  To clarify (sorry), I have been using pyqtgraph in conjunction with PyQt to display the images.

Comment: This is not related to Python at all, it is confusing that you say you don't know how to use scipy but gives a slightly impression that you might know a procedure to perform the task you are after. If you happen to have such procedure, then it makes the question much easier. As it stands, your question cannot be properly answered (but some people will say: use library bleh, use library bluh, check this question blah, etc). Can you include actual input that you expect to receive, what you intend to do with it, and what output you expect ? Better restrict what kind of objects you wanna track.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said how you produce your images. If you use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) for it, then you can quite easily create a nice GUI on top of it, see this question: [How can I create a frontend for matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285912/how-can-i-create-a-frontend-for-matplotlib)

In fact, matplotlib comes with a GUI neutral (working with any toolkit matplotlib supports: wxpython, tkinter, qt, fltk, macosx) way to handle events like clicking, see this page: [Event handling and picking](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)

Regarding object detection and tracking, have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) and this question: [How do I track motion using OpenCV in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374828/how-do-i-track-motion-using-opencv-in-python)