# How to take user input in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way of getting some input from a user in matplotlib? For example, a drop down list or a text box? What alternatives are there?

If there isn't anything, what would be the easiest way of displaying data based on what a user's input would be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285912/how-can-i-create-a-frontend-for-matplotlib

Answer (score 3):

This could be a very very WIDESPREAD answer...

What exactly do you mean when you say "input from user?"

if you are just talking about a textbox and an okay button then

```
raw_input('Enter your text')
```

If you're wanting something a bit more sophisticated and controllable I suggest looking into the [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) tools and creating your own [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) where you can create things like combo boxes, checkboxes, entry widgets, popup boxes, and a lot more.

if this doesn't exactly answer what you are asking please post an example of your code then add something like

```
code code code

#HERE YOU WOULD PUT WHAT YOU WANT TO ACCOMPLISH

code code code
```